# Move changes from VS 2005 to VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project

I have a project created on VS 2005(.cpp) which has now been migrated to VS 2012. Later, some changes have been made to the VS 2005 copy which now needs to be moved to the VS 2012 one. What are all the options availble for me?

Sorry if the page already exists but it would be helpful if you could comment with the link for the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a code versioning system, Take a diff in VS2005 project, and apply it in VS2012 copy.
If you do not use one, use a file compare tool (Araxis Merge, BeyondCompare, WinDiff) and try to find and copy differences.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. I have the list of modified files. My doubt is that whether just copying them to 2012 project and rebuilding them would work and the project could run correctly? I am trying out this but I would appreciate if you've any solutions as well. Thanks!

Comment: For this case, no one can give you advice, since no one has seen the code and its dependencies and the changes made, etc. You have to try it. If you changed only code files, it should probably work.